# How add two or more logger using different files?

Tags: node.js, express, logging, winston

I am working on node Js logging library. I am using winston for this.I created log files but I stuck when I want to create two log files.Suppose I have to create all log file which contain all logs and error log file which contain only error logs.But I stuck here:

```
if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
}
const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
let logger = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.Console)({
            level: 'debug',
            timestamp: tsFormat,
            handleExceptions: true,
            colorize: true,
            json: false
        }),
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            name: 'all-file',
            handleExceptions: true,
            filename: `${logDir}/all-file.log`,
            level: 'debug',
            maxsize: 100000000,
            json: true
        }),
        new(winston.transports.File)({
            name: 'error-file',
            handleExceptions: true,
            filename: `${logDir}/error-file.log`,
            level: 'error',
            maxsize: 100000000,
            json: false
        })
    ]
});
```

I want that error log show different type of console than debug console.But by default its only taking debug one. how can I manually add console config for both files.When I try to add another transport.console it shows error.

```
Transport already attached: console, assign a different name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var winston = require('winston');
let consoleLogger = function(options){
  return new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(options),
  ]
});
} 

// the CustomTransport is to prevent error log show multiple times 
class CustomTransport extends winston.Transport {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.options = options;
    this.levels = options && options.levels || [this.level];
  }

  log(level, msg, meta, callback) {
    if(this.levels.indexOf(level) > -1){
      consoleLogger(this.options)[level](msg, meta);
    }
    callback(null, true);
  }
}

winston.transports.CustomTransport = CustomTransport;

const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    // add name attribute to prevent Transport already attached error
    // no error log for this transport
      new (winston.transports.CustomTransport)(
        {
          name: 'info-console',
          level: 'debug',
          levels : ['debug', 'verbose', 'info', 'warn'],
          timestamp: tsFormat,
          handleExceptions: true,
          colorize: true,
          json: false
      }
      ),
      // only error log for this transport, modify the configuration as you need
      new (winston.transports.CustomTransport)(
        {
          name: 'error-console',
          level: 'error',
          timestamp: tsFormat,
          handleExceptions: true,
          colorize: true,
          json: false
        }
      ),
      new (winston.transports.File)(
          { 
              name: 'info-file',
              filename: 'info.log',
              timestamp: true,
              maxsize: 1024000,
              level: 'info'
          }),
      new (winston.transports.File)(
          { 
              name: 'error-file',
              filename: 'error.txt',
              timestamp: true,
              maxsize: 1024000,
              level: 'error'
          })
  ]});
```

usage:

```
 logger.debug('debug');
 logger.error('error');
```